# How do I add one document to solr index using solrj?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I can reindex an entire solr core using the following code:

```
 public void indexSolr() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(solrIndexPath);
    logger.info("Indexing fcv solr at " + solrIndexPath);

    // reindex to pickup new articles
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set("qt", "/" + solrDataImportPath);
    params.set("command", "full-import");
    params.set("clean", "true");
    params.set("commit", "true");
    solr.query(params);
}
```

How can I insert just one single document into the index without having to index the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public void insertOneDoc() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
  HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(solrIndexPath);
  SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
  doc.addField("fieldName", "fieldValue");
  solr.add(doc);
  solr.commit();
}
```

Because that adds a single document to your index that the HttpSolrServer refereces.

Comment: which version of solr4j did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm....I'm not sure if this is possible with DIH. I mean, depending on what you mean with "whole thing" (because a change in the index, even a single document, needs an index rebuild) you could index one document in this way

1) delta import
If that single record is somethjng that has been changed and that change is something you can identify with a database column (e.g. a timestamp), then you csn use the delta import capability of DIH

2) change & reload
- change the dih-config modifying the query to select that single record

- reload the DIH configuration
- re-issue the full import

Comment: you sure there isn't a way to just call something like `solr.add(document); solr.commit;`? I just haven't been able to find it documented anywhere.

Comment: Wait: my answer assumed you want to do that with DIH. Otherwise, if you can / want use a custom client (using Solrj or whatever) you can basically do whatever you want

Comment: Yes, I'm using solrj. Do you know how to add one document using that method?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't precise enough: Ok, you're using SolrJ but for controlling DIH, which (at least to me) it's a bit strange. Now, using this approach I don't think you can do what you want. For adding a single document, you should get from the database that record, convert it in a SolrInputDocument and then send to Solr. But of course, there's a lot of redundancy here