# Real time index in Solr using JAVA API

Tags: java, solr

```
Time T1 -> Create an index.
Time T2 -> Multiple users performing search using the index.
Time T2 -> Simultaneously in Time T2, New file needs to be added to index.
```

Is there a way in Solr (through JAVA API) to add new file to index in REAL TIME.

If yes, please let know, which JAVA API.

If no, I had planned for below approach, to handle above scenario.

```
Time T1 -> Create an index.
Time T2 -> when the new file arrives; create a copy of index object. To the new object; appending the index details for newly arrived file.
```

Please let know, if above approach is feasible.

Comment: You can use the [`solrj`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ) java api for performing all the different operation (add/update/delete/search) on solr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add one document to solr index using solrj?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521859/how-do-i-add-one-document-to-solr-index-using-solrj)

Comment: See [the SolrJ documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ)